# Javascript One after another method call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to javascript validation for `__NodeJS Rest API__`, but my problem is;

Validator Class

```
class Checks {

 constructor() {

 }

 object(field) {
  return field;
 }

 keys(field) {
   if(typeof field === "string") {
    return true;
   }
  return false;
 }

}

module.exports = Validator;
```

and I want to use

```
Validator.validate(field).string()
```

but error code:

Comment: If you want something like that, then the methods actually need to return a `Validator` or `this` instead of just a plain value. That's the general concept of how this works in places where you see it. Really does not make sense in the context you propose to use it though, so you really should give that more thought.

Comment: The way you've declared your class, you need to make an instance of your object with let v = new Validator()`.  Then, you can do `v.validate(field)`.  To do `v.validate(field).string()`, you would have to make `.validate()` return an object that has a `.string()` method on it.  Right now, you're returning `field` and it is not clear to us what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign field as a property of the current instance then return the `this` for chaining methods.

```
class Validator {

 constructor() {
   this.field = null;
 }

 validate(field) {
   this.field = field;
   return this;
 }

 string(field) {
   return typeof this.field === "string";
 }

}

module.exports = Validator;

//usage
const Validator = require('path/to/Validator');
new Validator().validate(field).string();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change like,

```
class Validator {

 constructor() {

 }


 validate(field) {
   if(typeof field === "string") {
    return true;
   }
  return false;
 }

}

module.exports = Validator;
```

And make a call like,

```
Validator.validate(field)
```

Or simply change the validate function as,

```
validate() {
  return this;
 }
```

And call it like,

```
Validator.validate().string(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//validator-factory.js

class ValidatorFactory {

  static validate(field) {
    return new Validator(field);
  }

}

class Validator {

 constructor(field) {
   this.field = field;
 }

 string() {
   if(typeof this.field === "string") {
    return true;
   }
  return false;
 }

}

module.exports = ValidatorFactory;
```

Then, import `ValidatorFactory` & use as follows

```
var ValidatorFactory = require('./validator-factory');
ValidatorFactory.validate(field).string();
```

Note the use of `static` keyword in `ValidatorFactory` & `validate` returns new instance of `Validator` class every time.